# What techniques are being used to find malicious code in PHP?

Tags: php, security

Currently, I have a copy of my web application on my testing server that is unaltered, and another folder used for development. Whenever I'm ready to go live with a version, I first copy it to the main "live copy" folder, then to the site. I have a script that looks at the exact file sizes, down to the byte, of all PHP files used in the live version on the site and compares it to the "live copy" sizes.

My hope is that in the event some malicious code is injected into my PHP files, the file size difference will show, and it will restore the files from the original.

I'm also searching the files for "eval(".

What else can I look for to check for malicious code?

Comment: How does your web application accept user input?

Comment: I accept input through forms that are parsed sever-side, mostly behind a login. One variable checks for a URL parameter sent be a device that is never seen by a user. All my database code is using prepared statements. But the security of my input is another question. I'm currently focused on scanning my server daily for changes, in case someone does break my site.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why would this get down-voted?

Comment: I honestly thought it was a valid question, however it admittedly took me a few times rereading it to understand your issue, so maybe it was a little unclear to others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: There a huge number of things you need to do in order to be assured of the security of our site - but your question specifically relates to ensuring code integrity. Also, it is only really applicable to small, low value sites. If you are running a command and control centre for nations missile defences or are a large bank then you need something a bit more sophisticated than I'll be describing here (sorry to state the obvious - but thought it advisable to clarify this in case another reader thinks that this has wider applicability).

Matching the file size is a start - but relatively easy to subvert - otoh generating a hash of the file (as implemented in most host based IDS) requires additional capability on the remote server.

Your search for "eval(" will not detect "eval (". It's also possible to inject code using include/require, create_function and preg_replace() (the last one has been removed in the most recent versions of PHP).

Depending on the amount of code, I would lean towards copying your production site locally and checking for changes in content locally rather than just looking at remote filesizes. Or at least generate a database of hashes on the server and download them for comparison. As long as you can be confident that the code you are deploying from your dev machine is clean, this should address both the processes you are currently carrying out.

Comment: Thanks for the info on "eval(". Not knowing injection techniques makes it difficult to create protective measures. My site is, in fact, a small and low value site. In fact, I'm using measures to show my devices a specific output and a PC gets redirected to a completely different URI. I like the idea of hashing the files too. The only input taken from the device side is hidden and controlled from by a device profile so that the user is never made aware of the input in the first place. Then, I'm working separately to secure my login on PCs.

Comment: Additionally, if your looking for a way to detect all instances of `eval()` no matter the spacing, the following regex should work: `/eval[ ]*\(/`

Comment: @C.Liddell Awesome, thanks. I'm going to need to add quite a few regex matches now :)

Comment: Better to use /\beval\b/i tabs and newlines can be used as well as spaces.